# Have I found a Chrome TextDecoder bug?

Tags: google-chrome, text, decode, decoder

**Tested with:** Chrome on Linux 70.0.3538.110
**Bug:** Previously failed `textDecoder.decode` call will cause failure of successive calls.

```js
const log = console.log
let string = 'Hello ♥ world! ♥'
let textEncoder = new TextEncoder()
let bytes = textEncoder.encode(string)
let textDecoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8', {fatal: true})
try {
  // Comment away this line and the code below will work
  log(textDecoder.decode(new DataView(bytes.buffer, 0, 19)))
} catch (e) {
  log('After this failed the next try will also fail')
}
log(textDecoder.decode(new DataView(bytes.buffer, 0, 20)))
```

Comment: I submitted the bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=910292 You could possibly help marking it as "confirmed".